# Which objects can be Minkowski halved?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, recreational-mathematics, polygons, fractals

The Minkowski Sum of two subsets $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is
$$A \oplus B = \{a + b | a \in A, b \in B\}$$
For a given $A$, is there some condition that tells me when I can find a $B$ such that $A = B \oplus B$?

---

For a specific example/context I was thinking about, let $K = $filled in Koch Snowflake in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then, $K \oplus K = $filled in hexagon. This is not too surprising given that there is theorem saying $\frac{1}{n} (A + \cdots n \text{ times} \cdots + A) \to \text{Convex Hull}(A)$, so $K$ is like half a hexagon (and perhaps, it is the 'smallest' half a hexagon, if you drop the filled-in-ness of it, up to a measure 0 set?). Is there something that is half of $K$?

Comment: For $\mathbb{R^2}$, See Fig. 2 in this past [answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3533500/305862) where, in a first approach, you should work with a "perturbated" solution $A=B \oplus B'$ where $B'$ is slightly different from $B$

Comment: You haven't commented my comment. What is the origin of this problem ?

Comment: Connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/544157/305862

Comment: I don't have any particularly strong motivation - I was just wondering as I wrote in the question whether you can halve the koch snowflake, and asked the general problem of how to know when I can Minkowski half an object

Comment: For all convex sets $A$, we have $\frac 12 A+\frac 12 A=A$. So for all convex sets $A$, $\frac 12A$ is the Minkowski halved of $A$.